# Flutter stripe integration and setupIntegration secret key

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, integration

From our backend, I receive this string: seti_1FbMdVFYVZR************_secret_G7brAOT5*********. I need to use this string now, to add a card to user, when he enters it in the app. Its like a wallet, where users can add and remove cards, and later use them to pay for stuff.

How can I now use this string, and stripe key, to add a card to wallet? I tried a few packages, but none seem to work.

Any help or recommendations are welcome!

Comment: to add a card to stripe you need to make 2 requests 1 to create card token and the in 2nd that card token and stripe customer id to create card.

Comment: Also you need to send stripe secret key sk_test in Authorization header with Bearer prefix